# hibernate: LazyInitializationException using netbeans and JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, netbeans, lazy-loading

I am using netbeans 7.1, glassfish 3.1.1 and hibernate 4.01
I am using the netbeans generated JSF files
- Facade.java
- Controller.java
and my own entity beans

In my baseTicket entity I have mapped the following

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "baseTicket", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
java.util.List<CustomAttribute> customAttributes;
```

If I add the `fetch=EAGER` annotation, I am able to access the customAttributes from the JSF web pages. However, if I leave it as lazy loading I get the

```
hibernate: LazyInitializationException
```

I have searched the web and tried many suggestions - but I cannot get this to work. 
I have tried creating an entity manager, but I cannot seem to be able to successfully create the em.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to load it eagerly you can write a named query to fetch the list in your DAO layer.

Annotation style:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "findCustomAttributes",
    query = "from CustomAttribute ca where ca.ticket = :ticketId"
    )
})
```

Here I am assuming there is link in CustomAttribute to Ticket (`@ManyToOne`) entity.

In Code you can fetch result as

```
Query query=em.createNamedQuery("findCustomAttributes");
query.setParameter("ticketId", 1);
List CustomAttributesList=query.getResultList();
```

You can use this list as required only thing is you need to know current Ticket id.

More info you can get from

1. [JEE6 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html)
2. [Hibernate JPA Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/)

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse - the problem is that I cannot seem to be able to get a valid reference to the entity manager in my entity itself.

Comment: @anthonys you dont need entity manager in entity its in your dao bean. Refer this [link](http://biese.wordpress.com/2007/10/08/service-layer-and-dao-architecture/) for some basic understanding of layered architecture and can refer [J2EE Pattern Catalog](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/index.html) for more understanding. Just check in code how they are fetching the entity now and appropriately fix it it must be in DAO layer.